# Openwrt SDK: Makefile permission denied

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I am compiling a user package with OpenWRT SDK. The src files are located in OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/package/adapter/src.

In the /adapter/src directory, I also have the Makefile:

```
adapter: adapter.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) adapter.o -o adapter
adapter.o: adapter.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c adapter.c
clean:
    rm *.o adapter
```

Running local make in /adapter/src directory works fine.

Then I added the following Makefile to /adapter directory:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
PKG_NAME:=adapter
PKG_RELEASE=1

PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/adapter
    SECTION:=utils
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    TITLE:=adapter --prints a dummy message
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(cp) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

define Package/adapter/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/adapter $(1)/bin
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,adapter))
```

And when I run make in the top directory, I got the following error:

```
zy@zy-OptiPlex-745:~/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686$ make V=99
Collecting package info: done
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/package/adapter'
mkdir -p /home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.11/adapter
./src/* /home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.11/adapter
bash: ./src/Makefile: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.11/adapter/.prepared_e0632caf1f416a667d5957a7f385ceb6] Error 126
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/package/adapter'
make[2]: *** [package/adapter/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686'
make[1]: *** [/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.11/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-i686'
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

Running make as root gives the same error. Can someone advise please? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your information,I think the error maybe cause by Makefile in /adapter directory.

```
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(cp) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
endef
```

should be modify like this:

```
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
endef
```

`$(CP)`is a variable,defined in rules.mk

`CP:=cp -fpR`

so you can use it to copy something.